# Slide between two files in Titanium

Tags: slider, titanium

I have done a slide between three windows using scrollView:

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    views:[viewDatos,viewDependientes,viewAsistencia]
});
```

Can I make a slide between two files .js in a Titanium app that I'm developing?

Comment: When you say "slide between files", are you talking about scrolling through text files?  Are you trying to view javascript files?  If not then I don't know what the ".js" in your sentence is.  Do you want to look at them side-by-side or one after the other?

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a tour or walk through  window then do like this

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#123' });
var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#246' });
var view3 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#48b' });

var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
  views:[view1,view2,view3],
  showPagingControl:true
});

win.add(scrollableView);
win.open()
```

Thanks

Comment: Boolean, set to false (default) to hide the paging control (the dots that show which page you're viewing)

Comment: oh, understood Wahabb. I'm using the same as you coded (scrolling views). What I want to know if there exists any technique to do the same but with different files (windows) no views.

Comment: Why you want to use window and i think if you would be giving the window there it would accept

Comment: I want to use window to separate code and not having all of it in only one .js